# Infinite radical ideal cubed equals zero for tame hereditary Artin algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a tame hereditary Artin algbera and mod$A$ the category of finitely generated (left) $A$-modules. Further, let rad$_A$ be the radical ideal of mod$A$, which is the smallest ideal containing all non-isomorphisms between indecomposable modules, and rad$_A^\omega$ the intersection of all finite powers of rad$_A$. I have seen the claim $($rad$_A^\omega)^3 = 0$ either without reference or for the case when $A$ is over an algebraically closed field multiple times. My question is: Is there any literature on this result when $A$ not over an algebraically closed field?

Answer (score 2):

I think that for tame hereditary algebras, the maps in the infinite radical go preprojective $\to$ regular $\to$ preinjective, so composing three of these gives zero.

A possible route to confirming this is as follows. Tame hereditary algebras are tame concealed (see for example Ringel, "Tame algebras and integral quadratic forms"). In the paper by Coelho, Marcos, Merklen and Skowroński, "Module categories with infinite radical cube zero" Section 3.3 it is proved that an Artin algebra is tame concealed if and only if the cube of the infinite radical is zero and there exists a faithful regular component.

Beware that I haven't checked what hidden assumptions there are in this.

Comment: In the introduction of "Tame algebras and integral quadratic forms" it states: "We fix some (commutative) field k, and for the sake of simplicity, we usually
will assume that k is algebraically closed."

Comment: I suspect that a lot of the literature around tame concealed algebras assumes that the field is algebraically closed. It's possible that this assumption is implicit in the paper of Coelho et al. This is unfortunate. Maybe someone more knowledgeable than I can comment on this.

Answer (score 2):

Any nonzero map between indecomposable preprojective modules cannot lie in the infinite radical.

For, we may as well assume the source is indecomposable projective. If there are $n$ indecomposable projectives, then any non-zero map in $\mathrm{rad}^n$ has target which is not projective, so it admits a nonzero map from $\tau^-A$. Now for any indecomposable preprojective, there is a maximal $N$ for which it admits a nonzero map from $\tau^{-N}A$.

Similarly for nonzero maps between indecomposable preinjective modules.

Finally, the same result holds for nonzero maps between indecomposable regular modules. This follows for example since they lie in a tube, so every morphism factors as a sequence of irreducible epimorphisms followed by a sequence of irreducible monomorphisms. So once we know the regular lengths of the source and target, we see that a sufficiently high power of the radical vanishes.

This shows that every nonzero morphism in the infinite radical is either from a preprojective to a regular or preinjective, or else from a regular to a preinjective.

Now every nonzero morphism in the square of the infinite radical must go from a preprojective to a preinjective, and every morphism in the cube of the infinite radical is zero.

Comment: Hi Andrew, good to hear from a real expert. This is how I thought things should behave, but are there any assumptions implicit in this, or does this work for an arbitrary tame hereditary Artin algebra? In particular, does this assume that no inseparability is happening behind the scenes? (I hate it when that happens)

Comment: I can’t see any problems, which is why I sketched the proof like this. For a finite dimensional tame hereditary algebra we always have the decomposition into preprojectives, regulars and preinjectives using the defect, and the regulars still form a tubular family.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, that's very helpful. - Dave

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a precise source for the claims? Espacially about the structure of the regular modules?